# Hibernate criteria or hql that returns rows older than two weeks

Tags: hibernate

How to write a hibernate criteria or hql that returns objects from database that are older than two weeks, knowing that those objects have a creationDate field?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Pseudocode

```
Calendar olederThanTwo = Calendar.getInstance() - 2_weks;
select creationDate < olederThanTwo;
```

A sketch of code

```
@Entity
class Persistent {

    @Column
    private Calendar creationDate; 

}

List<Persistent> getOlderThan(Calendar calendar) {
    session.createCriteria(Persistent.class);
    session.add(Restrictions.lt("creationDate", calendar));
    return session.list();
}

Calendar twoWeeksBefore = ...;

List<Persistent> result = getOlderThan(twoWeeksBefore);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try with below :

```
 List <Object> findByCreationDate(LocalDate dt);
```

and pass localdate to method as per below:

```
LocalDate subtracted = dt.minusWeeks(2);
```